# Getting Data from Firebase Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I just need to get the data "user_id" from Firebase and put it instead of xxx in condition (xxx == user_id). How can I do it? (look at the screenshots)

[image: Firebase Firestore]

[image: Android Studio]

Answer (score 0):

```
String postId = ""; // the post-Id from which you want the user_id
DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("Posts").document(postId);
docRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
        String userId = documentSnapshot.getString("user_id");
    }
});
```

The above code is for getting user_id when you know the post-id.
or do you want code for getting posts when you know the user_id

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, you just need to use a Query:

```
DocumentReference id = firebaseFirestore.collection("Posts");
Query query = id.whereEqualTo("user_id", user_id);
```

Using this code, you'll get the user which has the id as the value of `user_id` variable.